# Writing a filtered derivative term of the PID controller into the C++ code

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, applied-mechanics, control-theory, pid-control

Everywhere I look, be it a PID, lead, lag control or anything else, there are Simulink schematics with transfer functions. This is all nice for system response simulation, however currently I have to implement a PID control with a filtered derivative term into a strictly certified medical device, which is controlled by a microchip with a C++ code controlling it.

Now, if we take the PID controller in its frequency domain as

$$C(s) = k_\mathrm{P} + \frac{k_\mathrm{I}}{s} + k_\mathrm{D}s = \frac{y(s)}{e(s)},$$

we can implement that as

$$y(t) = k_\mathrm{P}e(t) + k_\mathrm{I}\int_{0}^{t}e(\tau)d\tau + k_\mathrm{D}\dot{e}(t), \quad e(0) = 0,$$

which we can write into pseudo code as

```
integral += error*dt
derivative = (error - prevError) / dt
y = kp*error + ki*integral + kd*derivative
prevError = error
```

However, now we take the filtered PID control as

$$C(s) = k_\mathrm{P} + \frac{k_\mathrm{I}}{s} + k_\mathrm{D}\frac{sN}{s + N}$$

The best I can think of is to create inverse Laplace as

$$y(t) = k_\mathrm{P}e(t) + k_\mathrm{I}\int_{0}^{t}e(\tau)d\tau + k_\mathrm{D}\left( N\delta(t) - N^2e^{-Nt} \right)e(t), \quad e(0) = 0,$$

but what does that really represent? Integrating via $dt$ is one thing, but all I can see in the $e^{-Nt}$ is the fact that after few seconds, no matter what I do, I am going to have just another proportional constant. Should I reset the time at some point? And we haven't even written that into C++ yet.

What is the correct approach?

Comment: Are you sure you want to apply derivative to error? Many commercial algorithms apply derivative action to the PV, so as NOT to kick the output on setpoint change.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have no idea whether this is correct, but the only thing that came to my mind after the night's sleep and a morning shower is the following:

My inverse Laplace is wrong, because I did not account for the error input $e(t)$ that is time variant. Therefore, if we look at the derivative part of the transfer function of the controller, we can write

$$C_\mathrm{D}(s) = \frac{sN}{s + N}.$$

Now we take whatever the error input there is and recreate the output as

$$y_\mathrm{D}(s) = \frac{sN}{s + N}e(s) \implies sy_\mathrm{D}(s) + Ny_\mathrm{D}(s) = Nse(s),$$

which can be transformed into time domain as

$$\dot{y}_\mathrm{D}(t) + Ny_\mathrm{D}(t) = N\dot{e}(t).$$

The solution for this differential equation is

$$y_\mathrm{D}(t) = \mathrm{constant} \times e^{-Nt} + e^{-Nt}\int_0^tN\dot{e}(\tau)e^{N\tau}d\tau, \quad y_\mathrm{D}(0) = 0, \quad e(0) = e_0.$$

This could be implemented into the code, but I don't fancy the absolute time $t$ being there, because we are talking embedded system with finite memory and about 120 MHz clock.

The other option is to discretize the differential equation as

$$\frac{y_\mathrm{D}^n - y_\mathrm{D}^{n - 1}}{\Delta t} + Ny_\mathrm{D}^{n} = N\frac{e^n - e^{n - 1}}{\Delta t}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N},$$

therefore

$$y_\mathrm{D}^n(1 + N\Delta t) = N\left( e^n - e^{n - 1} \right) + y_\mathrm{D}^{n - 1}, \quad y_\mathrm{D}^0 = 0, \quad e^0 = e_0,$$

where $n$ is the time-step, *not* power to the $n$. From this, we are able to compute the $y_\mathrm{D}^n$, sum it to the other two constants of the controller and feed that to the input of the actuators.

Well, the problem is that I am currently facing the fact that an embedded system will have to solve a differential equation, real-time. I don't know whether this is the correct approach in the industry, so I would be glad if anyone could point out a different solution. The problems I see with this are many - discretized equations are basically forward Euler, may this cause some problems? Shouldn't Runge-Kutta be used?

Comment: Runga-kutta is a numeric method for solving ODE's not for discretization.

Comment: Well of course, but you discretize the formula in a different manner, and... I want to solve an ODE.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following reference http://www.ifac-control.org/publications/list-of-professional-briefs/pb_wittenmark_etal_final.pdf, especially page 50. I think this should help you completely.

Comment: So as to avoid link-rot, please expand your answer to include the relevant information from the link provided, at least the most essential points. Feel free to quote directly from the source.